# Setting up a flow that draws from fields in a lookup relationship and is triggered via a button

Tags: visual-workflow

I am a new Salesforce admin and could use some help in setting up a screen flow that is triggered via a button.  I already have the button setup, but could use pointers regarding how to setup the flow.

The use case:  I want to add a "Retrigger Email" button to the Lead Record.  This button will send the email template associated with the Lead (`Email_Template_Id__c` on the Campaign on object) upon clicking.  The Lead has a `Primary_Campaign__c` field.  This field references the specific Campaign that contains the `Contacts_Email_List__c` field I want to send to and the `Email_Template_Id__c` used for the send.

The error I am getting is says - Error Occurred: Because you didn't specify an Email Template ID, the Subject parameter is required.

However, I have a template id on the campaign object.  I am drilling into that object in the Email action but I'm still getting this error.  Also, the error email says that the Subject parameter is required, but I don't see that specified in the Email Action.  The whole function of this button is to be able to manually resend an email that has already been sent (if client says "we didn't receive that email").  Below is a picture of when I debug the flow.

[image]

I have tried several different approaches but none have worked.  Here is what I have so far.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.  Thank you.

Pictures are:

1. Overview of flow
2. Lead Element
3. Campaign Element
4. Email Element

[image: Overview of flw]

[image: Lead Element]

[image: Campaign Element][image: Email Element]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Could you explain what you mean by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Please [edit] the question to clarify this point. Include exact wording for any error you do get.

Comment: and also use [edit] to show your button's URL

Comment: Thanks for the pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

within your screen flow, you should declare a variable that needs to be named exaclty `recordId` and be marked as available for input. If you bind this flow to a Quick Action and use the Quick Action as a Button on the Lead object, this will pass the Lead record into your flow. Then you don't need the first GetRecord element to read the lead.
[image]

In the Send Email Action, I guess you use the SimpleSendEmail that is shipped with Salesforce. If you hoover over the (i) of Recipient Address List you will find an explanation from Salesforce what it expects in this field. And I think you don't need this parameter.
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the feedback Andreas, I have implemented those changes and I am no longer receiving the "No records were found error", but the error I am getting now says " Because you didn't specify an Email Template ID, the Subject parameter is required."  It's like its not picking up on the values set in the campaign object for the Email Template Id.  Please feel free to refer to my edited post.

Comment: @Gaucho you can use the Debug functionality of the flow to exactly see what happens in every single step of your flow. Then you might see what went wrong in every step.